# how to prevent file upload when body validation fails in nestjs

Tags: node.js, validation, file-upload, nestjs, nest

I have the multipart form to be validated before file upload in nestjs application. the thing is that I don't want the file to be uploaded if validation of body fails.
here is how I wrote the code for.

```
// User controller method for create user with upload image
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image'))
create(
    @Body() userInput: CreateUserDto,
    @UploadedFile(
        new ParseFilePipe({
          validators: [
             // some validator here
          ]
        })
    ) image: Express.Multer.File,
) {
    return this.userService.create({ ...userInput, image: image.path });
}
```

Tried so many ways to turn around this issue, but didn't reach to any solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interceptors run before pipes do, so there's no way to make the saving of the file *not* happen unless you manage that yourself in your service. However, another option could be a custom exception filter that `unlink`s the file on error so that you don't have to worry about it post-upload

Comment: You are right, but how can I check for validation errors inside exception filter. I can not do it, I seems like no way I can check for validation errors before they are thrown

Comment: I edited my code I want to right a validator class which would check for validation errors if exists. if it exists then unlink the file.

Comment: The `ParseFilePipe` would throw a `BadRequestException`, so you could verify that that is the error type you are receiving in the filter

Comment: I did it using an exception filter on BadRequestException, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how I created the whole filter

```js
import { isArray } from 'lodash';
import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  BadRequestException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import * as fs from 'fs';

@Catch(BadRequestException)
export class DeleteFileOnErrorFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: BadRequestException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    const getFiles = (files: Express.Multer.File[] | unknown | undefined) => {
      if (!files) return [];
      if (isArray(files)) return files;
      return Object.values(files);
    };

    const filePaths = getFiles(request.files);

    for (const file of filePaths) {
      fs.unlink(file.path, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return err;
        }
      });
    }
    response.status(status).json(exception.getResponse());
  }
}
```

Comment: ElZombieIsra has written a good answer but he hasn't explained how to bind this BadRequestException in Nest.js. 

There are three major ways to do it:

Global Scope
Controller Scope
Method Scope.

This article explatins how to do it.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/exception-filters-in-nestjs/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using multer's memory storage & interceptor to save the file after controller has been called.
That way validation will run before saving file.
If validation fails, the request will skip the save file intercecptor & be handled by filter.

save-file.interceptor.ts

```
import {
    CallHandler,
    ExecutionContext,
    Injectable,
    NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { writeFile, existsSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class SaveFileInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

    saveFile(file: Express.Multer.File) {
        const fileType = file.mimetype ? file.mimetype.split('/')[0] : 'others';
        const destination = join(__dirname, `../../src/public/upload/${fileType}`);
        if (!existsSync(destination)) {
            mkdirSync(destination, { recursive: true });
        }
        writeFile(
            `${destination}/${file.filename}`,
            file.buffer,
            err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    throwError(err);
                }
            }
        )
    }

    generateFilePath(file: Express.Multer.File) {
        const fileType = file.mimetype ? file.mimetype.split('/')[0] : 'others';
        file.path = `/upload/${fileType}/${file.filename}`; // path served as static file
    }

    generateFileName(file: Express.Multer.File) {
        file.filename = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
    }

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

        const req: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        
        if (req.file) {
            this.generateFileName(req.file);
            this.generateFilePath(req.file);
        }
        if (req.files) {
            if (Array.isArray(req.files)) {
                req.files.forEach(file => {
                    this.generateFileName(file);
                    this.generateFilePath(file);
                });
            }
            else {
                Object.values(req.files).flat().forEach(file => {
                    this.generateFileName(file);
                    this.generateFilePath(file);
                });
            }
        }

        return next.handle().pipe(tap(() => {
            
            if (req.file) {
                this.saveFile(req.file);
            }
            if (req.files) {
                if (Array.isArray(req.files)) {
                    req.files.forEach(file => this.saveFile(file));
                }
                else {
                    Object.values(req.files).flat().forEach(file => this.saveFile(file));
                }
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

controller

```
import {
    Controller,
    Post,
    Body,
    UseInterceptors,
    UploadedFile,
    UploadedFiles,
    ParseFilePipeBuilder,
    HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Public } from '../auth/public.decorator';
import {
    FileFieldsInterceptor,
    FileInterceptor,
    FilesInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { FileTypeValidator, FileSizeValidator } from 'src/common';
import { SaveFileInterceptor } from 'src/interceptors/save-file.interceptor';
import { UploadOneFileDto } from './upload.dto';

@Public()
@Controller('upload')
export class UploadController {

    @Post('/one-file')
    @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('file'),
        SaveFileInterceptor
    )
    uploadOneFile(
        @UploadedFile(
            new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
                .addMaxSizeValidator({ maxSize: 1024 * 1024 })
                .addFileTypeValidator({ fileType: /.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/ })
                .build({ errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST }),
        ) file: Express.Multer.File,
        @Body() body: UploadOneFileDto
    ) {
        console.log(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for sharing your solution on StackOverflow. However, using screenshots of code can make it challenging for others to copy, modify, or understand your solution effectively. Consider replacing the screenshots with actual code blocks for better readability and accessibility. Feel free to [edit] your answer to make the code more accessible to everyone.

Comment: using `MemoryStorage` is not recommended in general bec your server will be susceptible to out-of-memory exceptions.

Comment: @MohamedSalah thanks for pointing that out, I wanted to validate file type based on the buffer so i needed to use memory storage. multer disk storage sadly doesn't provide file's buffer;